# Trying to get first Ajax program working, nothing dynamic happens

Tags: php, ajax, wamp

I'm basically copying [this example from w3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp) and when you start typing in a name a few suggestions get added. No suggestions are getting added for me.

**nameguess.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-ca">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ajaxing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function showHint(str)
            {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (str.length == 0)
            {
              document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
              return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
        //-->
        </script>
</head>
<body>
Hello.<br />
<form method="GET" action="">
    Name: <input type="text" id="txt1" /><br />
    Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

**gethint.php**

```
<?php
// Fill up array with names
$a[]="Anna";
//removed code to save space
$a[]="Vicky";

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
if (strlen($q) > 0)
  {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
    {
    if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint=$a[$i];
        }
      else
        {
        $hint=$hint." , ".$a[$i];
        }
      }
    }
  }

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint == "")
  {
  $response="no suggestion";
  }
else
  {
  $response=$hint;
  }

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

I have both files located in the www folder of WAMP and have the virtual server running.

Comment: "code for IE6, IE5" - Really?

Comment: Why not use something like [jQuery $.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? I find it to be much easier and cross-browser friendly.

Comment: where is the code that is calling showHint(str)

Comment: more rubbish from w3 idiots - please see why you should find a tutorial else where http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: @paul what is wrong with "code for IE6, IE5"?

Comment: @Dagon stackoverflow seems to be very split on w3c schools. The most upvoted answer when asking where to learn Ajax was a website that contains a list of long examples. The second most upvoted was w3c schools. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257110/ajax-tutorial

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, it just signifies a very old tutorial. You're better off finding something new as @Romuloux pointed out

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the key press event binding:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
```

Also, your PHP could be simplified as

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['q']) exit;

// Fill up array with names
$names = array("Anna", "Vicky");

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

$hints = array();
foreach($names as $name) {
   if (stripos($name, $q) !== -1) $hints[] = $name;
}

if(count($hints) == 0) die("no suggestion");

echo implode(', ', $hints);

?>
```

Comment: Is there a difference between onchange vs onkeyup?

Comment: Yes, `onchange` is fired when you take the focus from the input, but `keyup` as the name suggests fires every time you release a key.

Comment: And by the way, I second @Romuloux to suggest using a library like jQuery for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that others have already answered what you are trying to do but I would suggest not making your ajax requests like that example.

Instead try using the jQuery library to make your ajax requests. I was able to shorten up the code above into this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.get(
        'gethint.php', //Code behind 

        {q : $("#txt1").val()}, //json string of variables to post

        function(data){$("#txtHint").html(data);}, // What to do with return data

        'json'); //Specify json 
    </script>
```

It will make life much easier in the long run, because it stinks to have to go through that whole mess and have to worry about cross-browser compatibility.

You can find more information here [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Is there any benefit to learning it first the "hard way" and not using JQuery? Normally I learn 1 thing at a time.

Comment: In my personal opinion, no, but to each his own. If it fits your learning style, go for it. I was just trying to get you to the end faster (making a successful ajax query) than using a more complex method.

Comment: What the server returns is a comma separated list of names, not json.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeypress="showHint(this.value)"/>
```

and see if this helps

Comment: This only works if the user clicks another input field, and I only have 1.